# IF statement not returning true or false inside loop

Tags: apex

My code is supposed to be checking the Record Type Id of a newly inserted opportunity against a set of ids listed in a custom setting, then, if there's a match it should perform the calculation.

I have code coverage for all lines before line 22 -

```
if(opp.Annual_Settlement_Value__c > 0 && opp.Interchange_Rate_Revenue_as_a_percentag__c > 0)
```

but the formula is not returning either the result of the calculation or 0's for the fields listed in else{.

Trigger:

```
trigger FSRUpdate on Opportunity (before insert) {

    List<WEID__c> weids = WEID__c.getall().values();
    Set<Id> validRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (WEID__c weid : weids) {
        try {
            validRecordTypeIds.add(weid.WEOppId__c);
        } catch (System.StringException e) {
            System.debug(
                System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                'Invalid record type id ' + weid.WEOppId__c
                );
        }
    }

    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        if (validRecordTypeIds.contains(opp.RecordTypeId)) 
        {

            if(opp.Annual_Settlement_Value__c > 0 && opp.Interchange_Rate_Revenue_as_a_percentag__c > 0)
            {
                Decimal fsr = opp.Annual_Settlement_Value__c * opp.Interchange_Rate_Revenue_as_a_percentag__c;

                opp.FSR_Estimate_on_Contract_Signature__c = fsr;

            } 
            else 
            {
                opp.Annual_Settlement_Value__c = 0;
                opp.FSR_Estimate_on_Contract_Signature__c = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test class (I've deleted fields from this test class which would be required but aren't needed to test any part of the trigger):

```
@isTest
private class CP_FSRUpdateTest {

        //create custom setting to check Record Type Id against
        static testMethod void testCustSett() {

        WEID__c cs = new WEID__c();
        cs.Name = 'CP Virtual Prepaid MC';
        cs.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qif';
        cs.Name = 'Virtual Credit';
        cs.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qie';

        //causes error when missing a character
        cs.Name = 'Made Up Id';
        cs.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qa';
        insert cs;

        //test opportunity which satisfies all criteria
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.name = 'Test Opp';
        opp.RecordTypeId = '012700000005qif'; 

        //cover Revenue Values Required validation rule
        //(and provide values required for calculation)
        opp.Annual_Settlement_Value__c = 100.00;
        opp.Average_transaction_Value_POS__c = 1.00;

        opp.Interchange_Rate_Revenue_as_a_percentag__c = 0.1;

        insert opp;


        //Check with non-matching Record Type Id
        Opportunity usOpp = new Opportunity();

        usOpp.RecordTypeId = '012700000005r08';

        usOpp.name = 'US Opp';

        try{
            insert usOpp;
        } catch (Exception a) {
            System.debug('Wrong record type caused trigger to fail');
        }


        //Check no interchange rate
        Opportunity noIntOpp = new Opportunity(); 

        noIntOpp.Annual_Settlement_Value__c = null;
        noIntOpp.Interchange_Rate_Revenue_as_a_percentag__c = null;

        noIntOpp.name = 'No Interchange Opp';
        noIntOpp.RecordTypeId = '012700000005qif';
             system.AssertEquals(noIntOpp.FSR_Estimate_on_Contract_Signature__c,null);

        try{
            insert noIntOpp;
        } catch (Exception b) {
            System.debug('No interchange % caused trigger to fail');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've checked the debug log for any invalid record type ids?

Comment: Yes the only record type id that's listed is cs.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qa'; from the custom setting, not any of the id's from the test opportunities and that's showing as Error not Debug. So obviously the US Opp record type Id 012700000005r08 doesn't match the ids in the custom setting but that's not being picked up.

Comment: @NickCook In case it helps - removing a character from the record type id of US Opp caused the test to fail, it didn't trigger the system debug from my test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is this:

When you are doing this code:

```
WEID__c cs = new WEID__c();
        cs.Name = 'CP Virtual Prepaid MC';
        cs.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qif';
        cs.Name = 'Virtual Credit';
        cs.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qie';

        //causes error when missing a character
        cs.Name = 'Made Up Id';
        cs.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qa';
        insert cs;
```

The last value you set for the WEOppod__c is '012700000005qa'

So when you insert it that is the **ONLY** ID you will be putting into the validRecordTypeIDs in your trigger code.

THUS, you will not enter the block at `if (validRecordTypeIds.contains(opp.RecordTypeId))`.

So when you insert the pop, the recordtypeid of the inserted pop will not match.

I assume you want to enter a **LIST** of WEOppID__c records? If so change it to:

```
WEID__c[] csList = new WEID__c[]{};
WEID__c cs = New WEID__c();
        cs.Name = 'CP Virtual Prepaid MC';
        cs.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qif';
csList.add(cs);
WEID__c cs2 = New WEID__c();
        cs2.Name = 'Virtual Credit';
        cs2.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qie';
csList.add(cs2);
        //causes error when missing a character
WEID__c cs3 = New WEID__c();
        cs3.Name = 'Made Up Id';
        cs3.WEOppID__c = '012700000005qa';
csList.add(cs3);
        insert csList;
```

There are prettier was to do it in know but you get the gist...

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not worried about pretty! I'm getting a problem for cs.Name = 'CP Virtual Prepaid MC'; unexpected token '=' for some reason?

Comment: @AlexS - Make sure you have all the semi-colons correct? I do not see an immediate issue with the code I wrote so it may be where/how you are typing it.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I'll just test the solution..